# Django model design for tennis league

Tags: python, django, django-models

To learn web development, I'm developing a web app to help me manage our local tennis doubles league.  We play once weekly, and it works like this:

Based on their rank, players are assigned to a court each week.  The four players on each court play three Sets, changing partners for each Set.  A team wins a Set by winning 6 games:

- Set 1: Players 1 & 4 vs Players 2 & 3
- Set 2: Players 1 & 3 vs Players 2 & 4
- Set 3: Players 1 & 2 vs Players 3 & 4

After we finish, I evaluate the scores and recalculate each player's new rank.

Here are my Django models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_date = models.DateField()

class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Set(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team1_player1 = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name='+',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team1_player2 = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name='+',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team2_player1 = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name='+',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team2_player2 = models.ForeignKey(
        Player,
        related_name='+',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team1_games_won = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    team2_games_won = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

At minimum, I have a couple of concerns:

1. In the Set model, the Player ForeignKey attributes caused reverse
   accessor clashes, so I added related_name='+'.
2. If later I decide to retrieve a player's Set history, it would be nice to do      something like this:

> ```
> >>> p = Player.objects.get(id=1)
> >>> p.sets.all()
> ```

But without the reverse accessor, it's not that simple.

I can make it work, but I'm wondering if there is a better way than my Set model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making a team object, with many to many relationships for the players on them. This would mean you now have 6 teams (ex. red yellow green blue indigo violet) that may also help with organization. Labeling each set as team_x_player_x is hard work to remember.

This is how I would do it.

Event:

- date - datefield
- sets - manytomanyfield # all the sets played that day

Set:

- teams - manytomanyfield
- winner - foreignfield
- score - textfield (6-3)

Team:

- name - textfield (to simplify ex team red vs team blue)
- players - manytomanyfield

Player:

- user - foreignfield
- mmr - integer

Now you have a clearly defined hierarchy where an event has sets, sets have teams, and teams have players. It gets rid of the annoying issue you had with the related_name as well. You can now call `player.team.all()` and set all the teams that player plays on. You can also get `team.set.all()` to get all the sets each team has played in.

Comment: You could even separate it out further and add a match model, where each set has multiple matches too, instead of just keeping the score in a text field.

Comment: After reading through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674785/should-a-two-to-many-data-relationship-be-treated-as-many-to-many), I'm hesitant to use ManyToMany in this situation.  I may go with something similar to [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1672860).

Comment: Django makes many-to-many fields extremely easy to use, which was why I suggested them. In the second link, they are using a (modified) many-to-many as well, namely the TblMatch_PlayerScores which links players to a match.